# Can not add geospatial-tools dependency to Palantir Foundry code repository

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

Nothing is returned when I attempt to add the package per the documentation's instructions on how to enable spatial queries. Have geospatial-tools been removed?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by working with a Palantir support engineer. The problem was with the stack itself not allowing access to the package. I'm not 100% sure what the engineer did to configure the cluster, but once he was done, I was able to install the lib using the UI.